# iframe only working with some sites in Safari

Tags: iframe, safari

I have two iframe's below. One works in safari and one does not. I cannot seem to figure out why this is happening.

If the iframe will cause problems with soultion, can you recommend a solution for embedding a web page within a web page?

Thanks!!!

This works on Safari:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>iframe Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://ebay.com" width="100%" height="400"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

This does not work on Safari

```
<html>
<head>
<title>iframe Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://public.bullhornstaffing.com/JobBoard/Standard/default.cfm?privateLabelID=7327" width="100%" height="400"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. It looks like that website is setup to not be allowed to be embedded in an iFrame.

Answer (score 1):

The URL you listed requires four cookies to be installed before loading the page.  Safari doesn't load the cookies when accessed via an iframe.  If you open the url directly in another tab - it loads fine and then refreshing the iframe tab loads the iframe without error. Delete the cookies and the iframe doesn't load again.  The cookies in part direct a redirect.

This is a bug on the iframe target side of the equation.  Its not loading the cookies into safari via the iframe.  It loads fine in Chrome.